# Refetch apple credentials (Apple Sign in using Expo)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I read in the [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/apple-authentication/#appleauthenticationsigninasyncoptions) that the email and name of the user will only be provided the first time the user signs into the app and in subsequent requests will return `null`. However, I wasnt able to store the user credential the first time I signed in. How can I get the credential values again?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Expo but the values returned to me were still `null`.

Comment: You need to delete the Sign In with Apple association for your app in the Apple ID settings and sign up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not able to get the user details if we signed in before using the apple account until we are not removing the account access from apple settings.

So at the first time when we signing the user using an apple account, we have to store the user details somewhere like the backend or firebase database so we can get it back whenever we want.